# Select value of first row where column value matches

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, vlookup, transpose, google-query-language

I have two sheets in the Google sheet with the following pattern and data

**raw sheet**

| Projects | start date | end date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Proj1 | July 1, 2021 | July 10, 2022 | In Progress |
| Proj2 | July 11, 2021 | July 20, 2022 | Done |
| Proj1 | July 21, 2021 | July 25, 2022 | Done |

and another sheet

**project analysis**

| Projects | start date | end date | status | Time taken (days) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Proj1 | July 1, 2021 | July 25, 2022 | Done | 24 |
| Proj2 | July 11, 2021 | July 20, 2022 | Done | 10 |

The values in the **project analysis** has been manually field, but I want it to automate as follow

- set `start date` in **project analysis** to the `start date` column of the first entry from **raw sheet**
- set `end date` in **project analysis** to the `end date` column of the first entry from **raw sheet** where `status` is **Done**

How can I accomplish this in Google sheet?

Comment: How can Proj1 be both "In Progress" and "Done" either it is complete or it is not. Unless it moves in time... as it has two start dates :)

Comment: @SolarMike first sheet is the raw sheet, where every moment is recorded. The date has changed for the movement of `Proj1`. the `Proj1` was moved in between because of `Proj2` and after it has been done, `Proj1` starts again.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:C, B:C*1}, 
 "select Col1,min(Col2),max(Col3),'Done',max(Col5)-min(Col4) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label min(Col2)'start date',max(Col3)'end date','Done''status',max(Col5)-min(Col4)'time taken in days'", 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In excel ---

Formula in Column B

```
=VLOOKUP(A13,$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```

Array formula in Column C

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$4,MATCH(1,(A13=$A$2:$A$4)*("Done"=$D$2:$D$4),0))
```

Refer [INDEX and MATCH with multiple criteria](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria)

Formula in Column D

```
=IF(NOT(ISNA(C13)),"Done","In Progress")
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

start date:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(A2:A,raw!A:B,2,FALSE)))
```

end date:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(A2:A,FILTER(raw!A:C,raw!D:D="Done"),3,FALSE)))
```